# Python--Timedelta expression ignoring days (treating 6 mins the same as 24 hours + 6mins)

Tags: python, django, datetime

I'm trying to calculate the number of hours since a post has gone live.  It works, except it treats 24 hours later as 0 hours.  In other words, it seems to just subtract the current time from the baseline time without taking into consideration day differentials.

```
    def hours_live(self):
         diff=((datetime.datetime.today() - self.created).seconds)/3600
         return '%d Hours Ago' %diff
```

self.created refers to a Django DateTimeField:

```
      created=models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

What am I missing about the datetime object here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You want `total_seconds()`, not `seconds`.

Comment: Thanks Mark, the python docs don't seem to explicitly show that the .seconds attribute doesn't work in this case (though total_seconds is described well).  Appreciate it.

Answer (score 3):

Don't forget you can use Django `timesince` filter too as an option :)

```
>>> import datetime
>>> past = datetime.datetime.now() - datetime.timedelta(hours=6, minutes=20)
>>>
>>> from django.template.defaultfilters import timesince
>>> timesince(past)
u'6 hours, 20 minutes'
```